# how to filter a table based on predicates involving column values

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I would like to select a small subset of rows of a table based on a predicate involving multiple columns.

Here's a small example of what I want using For[]:

```
For[n = 10, n < 1000, n++, 
 If[n^3 < 15 n^2, Print[n, " ", n^3, " ", 15 n^2]]
 ]
```

10 1000 1500

11 1331 1815

12 1728 2160

13 2197 2535

14 2744 2940

I understand that using For[] is not good Mathematica style, so I tried to do this with Table[] and Select[]. So although Table[] will generate all the rows, I can't seem to get Select[] to filter out the rows that I don't want.

How would one do this without using For[] in good Mathematica style?

Comment: Do you already have a table given (e.g. some dataset from another source) or do you want to build it?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher  I'm going to create the rows on the fly, but only want to output the ones matching the predicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already have a table `tab` given and you want to filter it, probably the easiest way (but not exactly the most efficient) is by using `Select`:

```
tab = Table[{n, n^3, 15 n^2}, {n, 10, 1000}];(* creating the table *)
result = Select[tab, X \[Function] X[[2]] < X[[3]]]
```

> {{10, 1000, 1500}, {11, 1331, 1815}, {12, 1728, 2160}, {13, 2197, 2535}, {14, 2744, 2940}}

If you want to build the table `result` but if you do not want to build the full input table `tab` (e.g., for memory reasons), you can also use `Sow` and `Reap`:

```
result = Reap[
  Do[If[n^3 < 15 n^2, Sow[{n, n^3, 15 n^2}]], {n, 10, 1000}]
  ][[2, 1]]
```

> {{10, 1000, 1500}, {11, 1331, 1815}, {12, 1728, 2160}, {13, 2197, 2535}, {14, 2744, 2940}}

Unless the number of `n` to try is not too large, the first method will be faster, because it utilizes a [packed array](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496). The latter method needs some overhead to manage a more flexible data structure.

Well, the thing about packed arrays is probably too much detail for you at the moment...

You use `Print` to print the results into the notebook. If you want to use them later, you should store the results in an array as I did in the examples.